# how do I convert an ListViewItem to a ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I want to create a ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection object from a ListViewItem.
That's my approach:

```
public ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection getSelectedListViewItemCollection(ListViewItem myListViewItem)
{
    ListView myListView = new ListView();
    ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)myListViewItem.Clone();
    listViewItem.Selected = true;
    myListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    return new ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection(myListView);
}
```

However, an empty list is returned. (The list was supposed to contain the given listViewItem)
What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Can you give us a little broader picture? What are you trying to do with the return value here? I suspect there's a better way to achieve whatever it is you're aiming to do.

Comment: You should return `IEnumerable<T>` instead.

Comment: Never tried it, but I would have said Clone was the problem. As selected items should be those items where selected is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedListViewItemCollection is just a wrapper for a ListView with ListViewItems whose Selected property is true.  But, the ListView must be visible for it to work correctly.

If what you want is to have a collection of ListView items that are not selected on screen, then you shouldn't use SelectedListViewItemCollection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to get a list (or collection), which is what a `ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection` is, from a `ListViewItem`, which is a single item in a ListView control? It seems like you would want the inverse, which is to get a list of selected items from the `ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection`. Is that correct? If so, where is one way you can achieve that.

Given you have a list of `User` objects, your listview could be filled like this:

```
listview.BeginUpdate();
foreach (User u in userList)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem() { Text = u.Name, Tag = u};
    listview.Items.Add(item);
}
listview.EndUpdate();
```

where `userList` is a typed list of `User` objects, i.e. `List<User>`. You can then get the selected items in the ListView:

```
ListViewItem[] collection = GetSelectedItems(listview);

List<string> names = new List<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(collection, item =>
{
    User u = item.Tag as User;
    names.Add(u.Name);
});

private static ListViewItem[] GetSelectedItems(ListView listView)
{
    ListViewItem[] selectedItems = new ListViewItem[0];

    MethodInvoker miGetSelectedItems = delegate
    {
        selectedItems = new ListViewItem[listview.SelectedItems.Count];
        listview.SelectedItems.CopyTo(selectedItems, 0);
    };

    if (listview.InvokeRequired)
    {
        listview.Invoke(miGetSelectedItems);
    }
    else
    {
        miGetSelectedItems();
    }

    return selectedItems;
}
```

I hope this will help. Good Luck!